# To create a 4 column responsive row with equal width and height without using tables?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 4 column responsive row with each column having equal width and height which are responsive too. I am able to handle width, but not able to handle the height. Also, the image inside the column should be responsive.
I have attached my code below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Hello There</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- Given width:400px and height: 50px-->
  <div class="search">
    <input class="search-box" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-elements">
      <img       src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0d/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg/600px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-blue_square.svg.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-elements">
      <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonballfanon/images/7/70/Random.png/revision/latest?cb=20161221030547">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-elements">
      <img src="http://kb4images.com/images/random-image/37670495-random-image.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-elements">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTS1hevM-88hmiqyYOeeCeVUTzCS63jl31LEyLAIjY7AKWXDVe">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the css code:

```
.header
{
  text-align:center;
}

.search
{
  margin: 25px 1.5%;
}

.search input
{
  display:block;
  margin:0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid #f26522;
  border-radius:5px;
}

.grid
{
  display:flex;
}

.grid-elements
{
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  margin:1.5%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:3px;
}

.grid-elements img
{

 max-width: 100%;
 max-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
.grid-elements
{
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  margin:1.5%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

With:

```
.grid-elements
{
  flex: 1;
  margin:1.5%;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-radius:3px;
}
```

`flex: 1` will make all elements to take up the same amount of space in the parent `flex` container.

**[Working Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rvBZLx)**

Answer (score 1):

Here try using CSS Grid

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-elements {
  align-self: center;
}

.grid-elements img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ksqmy5r6/6/